# scala.html code color appearance

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea, playframework

Sorry for the stupid question. But I **don't want to mess around testing** things on the tutorial I am doing of play framework.

The problem is simple.

**I want this**

[image]

**But I am getting this**

[image]

*I am talking about the **color** difference.*

Looks like the need of scala **plugin** or something similar. But I am not sure.

P.S.I am using **Intellij.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need Scala plugin for your IntelliJ IDEA as you said. You may check out here. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+for+IntelliJ+IDEA